# RSpec should_receive macro that includes id of what needs to be tested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

How can I write this so it passes without hardcoding `1`. Chicken and the egg.

```
@sender = Factory(:user)
@receiver = Factory(:user)

mailer = double
mailer.should_receive(:deliver)
Mailer.should_receive(:email).with(1, @sender.id, @receiver.id).and_return(mailer)

# This will create an object with id #1 to make this test pass
@object = Object.create(:sender => @sender, :receiver => @receiver)
```

Comment: i think rspec uses should-matchers to verify the expected arguments on 'should_receive', otherwise things like anything() could not work? my idea would be to write an own argument matcher, which matches to the first id in the database.

Comment: While this is still a problem in the abstract here, I resolved it in my specific problem. I turned deliveries on in `test.rb` and am using `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` to test mailing.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
Mailer.should_receive(:email).with(an_instance_of(Fixnum), @sender.id, @receiver.id).and_return(mailer)
```