# integration tests for devise password recovery using rspec, capybara and email_spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, email-spec

I'm trying to test the password recovery using rspec/capybara using email_spec

My test.rb contains:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

My test goes like this:

```
feature User do
  let!(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  before(:each) do
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign up/in"
  end

  scenario "recover password" do
    user.save!
    click_link "Forgot password?"
    fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
    click_button "Send me reset password instructions"
    unread_emails_for(user.email).should be_present
  end
```

My test fails like so:

```
  1) User recover password
     Failure/Error: click_button "Send me reset password instructions"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter,
       set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

If I set the default_url_options, rspec tries to send the mail. I'm not too sure about :only_path.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284413/how-to-test-with-rspec-if-an-email-is-delivered-by-the-controller

Answer (score 3):

Set the following line in the `/config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```