# Deliver later not working in the test environment in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

Basically, with the test config set up exactly how it worked in Rails 4 (delivery method set as test etc), aside from deprecated options which I have replaced, mail only sends with deliver_now, not deliver_later. Deliver_later works in the development environment, even when the config is identical between the two environments.

Test environment mailer config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: have you tried to set `active_job.queue_adapter`?

Comment: from `test.rb` comment: The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array. so why do you want them to be sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same issue, and i have instead resorted to using assertions on

```
enqueued_jobs.size
```

to assert my mail has been queued. Additionally i have unit tests on the mailer class where i use deliver_now.

This requires including ActiveJob:TestHelper

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper
end
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That project is on the back burner and the rails 5 branch got stale but when I get round to revisiting it this should get everything passing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for testing emails that use deliver_later (Active Job) is to put the code you want executed now (not queued) and your assertions in a perform_enqueued_jobs block. This also requires adding an include at the top of your test file just below the class definition

```
include ActiveJob::TestHelper
```

Then something like the below.

```
perform_enqueued_jobs do
  post article_url, params: { article: { title: "Learn Testing", body: "Lorem Ipsum" } }
  assert_not_equal 0, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this actually attempt to send the mails?