# Rspec testing callback method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a model with the following callback:

```
class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_delighted_survey

  def send_delighted_survey

    position = client&.check_ins&.reverse&.index(self)
    
    if position.present? && type_of_weighin.present?
        survey = SurveyRequirement.find_by(position: [position, "*"], type_of_weighin: [type_of_weighin, "*"])

        if survey.present?
            survey.delighted_survey.sendSurvey(client: self.client, additional_properties: {delay: 3600})
        end
    end
  end
end
```

I am attempting to test the line: `survey.delighted_survey.sendSurvey(client: self.client, additional_properties: {delay: 3600})` to ensure that the correct `delighted_survey` is receiving `sendSurvey`.

This test passes:

```
let!(:week_1_sr) { create(:survey_requirement, :week_1_survey) }

it "should fire a CSAT survey after week 1" do
    expect_any_instance_of(DelightedSurvey).to receive(:sendSurvey).once
    create(:check_in, client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: "standard")
    create(:check_in, client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: "standard")
end
```

However this test fails and I don't understand why

```
let!(:week_1_sr) { create(:survey_requirement, :week_1_survey) }

it "should fire a CSAT survey after week 1" do
    expect(week_1_sr.delighted_survey).to receive(:sendSurvey).once
    create(:check_in, client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: "standard")
    create(:check_in, client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: "standard")
end
```

When I add print statements, it's definitely calling `sendsurvey` on `week_1_sr.delighted_survey` so I don't understand why the test fails.

How should I rearrange this test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience this is a common misunderstanding with `expect(..).to receive` when dealing with ActiveRecord.

We have to remember that the ActiveRecord object we create in our test stores a row in the database, the code in your model loads the row from the database and populates an entirely different activerecord object that is completely unconnected from the one in your test, except that they both refer to the same underlying database row.

Rspec is not "smart" about activerecord and the method you're stubbing/expecting is only on the instance of object in your test.

So how to fix this. The most direct option is to stub out the object that your code actually uses. This isn't easy, however, since it's an object returned from a method on another object returned by `SurveyRequirement.find_by(...)`. You can do it with something like:

#### Option 1 - Stub everything

```rb
survey_requirement_stub = double(SurveyRequirement)
survey_stub = double(Survey)
allow(SurveyRequirement).to receive(:find_by).and_return(survey_requirement_stub)
allow(survey_requirement_stub).to receive(:delighted_survey).and_return(survey_stub)

expect(survey_stub).to receive(:sendSurvey).once
```

However I wouldn't recommend this. It closely ties your test to the internal implementation of your method. e.g. Adding a scope (`scoped.find_by` instead of `find_by`) breaks the test in a way that's not meaningful.

#### Option 2 - Test the results, not the implementation

If the point of `sendSurvey` is [enqueuing a background job](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher) or [sending an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284413/how-to-test-with-rspec-if-an-email-is-delivered/7284748), that may be be a better place to test that it's doing what's expected, for example:

```rb
expect { create_checkin }.to have_enqueued_job(MyEmailJob)
# or, if it sends right away
expect { create_checkin }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
```

I think this approach is OK, but the implementation means that your code will be enqueuing jobs and firing emails throughout your test base. It will not be possible to create a `check-in` and *not* fire these.

This is why I **strongly** advise our engineers to **NEVER** use activerecord callbacks for business logic like this.

Instead...

#### Option 3 - Refactor to use service objects / interactors instead

As your application grows, using activerecord callbacks to create other records, update records, or trigger side-effects (like emails) becomes a significant anti-pattern. I'd take this as an opportunity to restructure the code to be easier to test and [remove business logic from your ActiveRecord objects](https://www.google.com/search?q=activerecord%20objects%20busines%20slogic&oq=activerecord%20objects%20busines%20slogic&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30j69i60l4.3626j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

This should make each part of this easier to test (e.g. is the survey-requirement looked up correctly? Does it send?). I've run out of time but here's the general idea:

```rb
class CheckIn
  def get_survey_requirement
    position = client&.check_ins&.reverse&.index(self)
    return unless position.present? && type_of_weighin.present?

    SurveyRequirement.find_by(position: [position, "*"], type_of_weighin: [type_of_weighin, "*"])
  end
end
class CheckInCreater
  def self.call(params)
    check_in = CheckIn.build(params)
    check_in.save!
    DelightedSurveySender.call(check_in)
  end
end
class DelightedSurveySender
  def self.call(check_in)
    survey = check_in.survey_requirement&.delighted_survey
    return unless survey

    survey.send_survey(client: check_in.client, additional_properties: {delay: 3600})
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! Extremely thorough and thought provoking.  I'm incorporating many of these ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `week_1_sr.delighted_survey` in spec and `survey.delighted_survey` aren't the same instance. Yes, both are instances of the same class and they both represent the same record in the database and same model behavior, but they do not have the same `object_id`.

In your first test, you are expecting that `any instance of DelightedSurvey` receives the method and that's, indeed, true. But in your second spec, you expect that that exact instance receives `sendSurvey`.

There are many ways to rearrange your test. In fact, if you ask 100 developers how to test something, you will get 100 different answers.

There is this approach:

```rb
let(:create_week_1_sr) { create(:survey_requirement, :week_1_survey) }

it "should fire a CSAT survey after week 1" do
  week_1_sr = create_week_1_sr # I don't think DRY is the better approach for testing, but it's just my opinion
  allow(SurveyRequirement).to(receive(:find_by).and_return(week_1_sr))
  delighted_survey_spy = instance_spy(DelightedSurvey)
  allow(week_1_sr).to(receive(:delighted_survey).and_return(delighted_survey_spy))

  create(:check_in, client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: "standard")
  create(:check_in, client_id: client.id, type_of_weighin: "standard")

  expect(delighted_survey_spy).to(have_received(:sendSurvey))
end
```

First thing about the test I wrote: Arrange, Act and Assert. It's clear to me where I am arranging my test, where I am acting and where I am asserting.

But you can realize that this test is polluted and has some prejudicial mocks. Like:

```rb
allow(SurveyRequirement).to(receive(:find_by).and_return(week_1_sr))
```

It will return `week_1_sr` even if you pass a wrong parameter to `find_by` (you can workaround it using `with`, but it will add logic to your tests).

You can see that it's pretty hard to test and I would agree. So would you consider removing this logic to a service class or whatever?

Oh, and just a heads up: `after_create` will be triggered even if the record is not commited for whatever reason. So you might consider using [after_create_commit](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_create_commit)

(just finished and got the notice of melcher's answer. his is better)